# Is there any fast ray→surface intersection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, language-agnostic, raytracing

Triangles are surfaces with a very simple `ray→triangle` intersection algorithm which can be done with a few operations. They are often used as primitives for ray-tracing applications for this reason - a mesh is, for example, approximated by a collection of triangles. The problem is, the more detailed the approximation, the more triangles you need, which means more tests. If your object is a perfect sphere, then using triangles might not be a good idea, since there is an O(1) algorithm that can test directly for `ray→sphere` intersections with few operations.

My question is: what other surfaces have that property of "having a faster `ray→surface`" intersection than the triangularization approach? Is there any mathematical structure/object that allows us to approximate the surface of an arbitrary 3D object and check for its intersection in O(1)?

Comment: You could tile your surface with spline patches or something.  Finding the intersection of a ray with a spline patch takes constant time, but it is no cakewalk.

Comment: I think ellipsoids or 3D boxes are easier but not as precise you need use the simplest objects that best fit your mesh shape Can use any geometry shape that can be represented by a math formula for this ... without knowing the shape (arbitrary mesh) is this hard. The object surface fitting is very slow process but it can be precomputed once  so it will not slowing runtime ...

Comment: continuous smooth surfaces with simple equations. such as ellipsoids (and spheres) and planes, and a cylindrical surface. Not angular shapes like cuboids (they are O(No. of faces))

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah is correct, continuous smooth surfaces with simple equations, for example, conic sections. I'll add axis-aligned bounding boxes: there are fast intersection algorithms for AABBs that would probably be superior in terms of runtime with testing intersection on an arbitrary cuboid composed of triangles (presumably with 12 at 2 per face).

Answer (score 2):

What knowledge do you have on your shape ?
- pure close form : some have close solutions.
- if it's just a triangle soup, you need some data structure for accelerate: e.g. grids, octrees, bounding box hierarchy, BSP...
- if you can express a potential or distance function - even approximate -  such as implicit surface, you can use dichotomy to get the intersection (iterations are quite fast).

( Or you can join the SparseVoxels community, but this is another story ;-) ).